# Import an Access Table in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I have to import information from an Access files, Test.accdb, and a table called "CONFIG".

I have many of the Access files, they are always generated in the same way and the table of interest is always "CONFIG".

The idea is to extract all of these tables to compile a database of them in Excel.

Not having any experience with Access, I used the macro recorder from Excel:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="CONFIG", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Astrashar\Desktop\Projet\Test.accdb""), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _CONFIG = Source{[Schema="""",Item=""CONFIG""]}[Data]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _CONFIG"

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""CONFIG"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [CONFIG]")
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "CONFIG"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

The code works, but when I try to modify ""C:\Users\Astrashar\Desktop\Projet\Test.accdb"" in the code to put up a variable, call it as "Path", I get an Error:

> 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error".

The re-worked code is below:

```
Dim Path
Path = "C:\Users\Astrashar\Desktop\Projet\Test.accdb"

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="CONFIG", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "   ' Source = Access.Database(File.Contents(""Path""), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _CONFIG = Source{[Schema="""",Item=""CONFIG""]}[Data]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    _CONFIG"
```

I've tried to defined Path as String, add, remove double-quotes and so on.

Comment: Welcome to SO. May I suggest you a different aproach? I mean, I have read *and the table of interest is always "CONFIG". The idea is to extract all of these tables to compile a database of them in Excel.* I suggest to use [Range.CopyFromRecordset Method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset). I think it would be the best way to compile all your *configs* table. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenating variables is done with `&` and not putting them between `"`. Otherwise you are referring to the name of the variable itself, and not its value. In the specific question, this:

- `...File.Contents(""Path""), [CreateNavigationProperties...`

should be:

- `...File.Contents(" & Path & "), [CreateNavigationProperties...`

to be able to get the value of `Path`. There could be another error somewhere.

---

This is a minmal example, concatenating string variable in Excel with other strings:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\Astrashar\Desktop\Projet\Test.accdb"    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Some predefined text " + path

End Sub
```

Getting this in A1:

[image]

Comment: Vityata, I've tried concatenating 'Path' but I still get an Error 1004. I've tried ...File.Contents(" & Path & ") and .File.Contents( Path ). Neither works unfortunately.

Comment: @Astrashar - too many things are strings, when they should be variables. E.g., if you want to get the contents of Path through `Access.Database(File.Contents(""Path"")`, then there should be no `"` in front of it, because it makes it a string. Follow the small example in `TestMe()` above and use `&` to concatenate the variables in a string.

Comment: Vityata - the TestMe() example works fine, I've never had an issue with concatenations in the past. Which is my current problem. In this case, I get these double  ""  in front of the file path. They appear in the original code as well. What I don't understand is that  File.Contents()  seems to work with a String as Input. FileContents(Path) ought to work but...doesn't

Comment: @Astrashar - can you edit your question, writing explicitly 2 lines. One that works (with the path written as the address) and one that does not work (with the path as a variable)? It would ease the work. Just make sure that you add only two lines, thus it is easier.